# GWT - VerticalPanel declared as static issue

Tags: gwt

I am trying to access the variable VerticalPanel declared as static, but it returns the latest value of that panel, how to get the triggered Panel details

Comment: why do you need to make static?

Comment: I want to access the variable in another class without instantiating it ..

Comment: Can you show us the used code?

Comment: class WindowPanel
{
 
  SingleViewPanel svp ; // another class  

------------
---------
}


I want to access the above variable without instantiating the WindowPanel class,

WindowPanel.svp // like this but without using static

I want some ideas to use get() and set()..

Comment: Tried with Singleton Pattern? Or better with Dependency Injection?